# Rails 6: Getting warning: previous definition of Socket was here rails aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::Cors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I try rails db:create I get
warning: previous definition of Socket was here
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::Cors

I am trying to create db . I am new to rails so am not sure what to do. I am trying to setup the project on my local.

Comment: Could yo share more info? Versions, the error code, or more context?

Comment: Is it a new app from scratch or you have upgraded from rails 5 to rails 6?

Comment: @Julian I recently joined a company and I was setting up an existing project on my system.  I was just following the steps mentioned in the README file. Installed node and yarn. Now when I try rails db:create am getting an error

Comment: @Payal am installing rails app which i git cloned

Comment: Can you confirm gem 'rack-cors' is part of your gemfile?

Comment: try: `bundle install` and also make sure that you have your db daemon running on the correct port.